# touchevent event function inside jQuery document

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, touch, jquery-events

I have the following event function inside jQuery document ready function:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function touchStart( e ) {
             var targetEvent =  e.touches.item(0);
             var y = targetEvent.clientY;
             var x = targetEvent.clientX;

             $('.display').text("X Y:"+x+" "+y);

             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
        }



    });
```

It works if I place it outside the `$(document).ready` but not inside it.. why?

If I want to use some jQuery on `touchStart` what would be the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).bind('touchstart',
    function( e ) {
         var targetEvent =  e.touches.item(0);
         var y = targetEvent.clientY;
         var x = targetEvent.clientX;

         $('.display').text("X Y:"+x+" "+y);

         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
    });
});
```